# How do I securely handle passwords in a Java Servlet Filter?

Tags: java, security, servlets, filter, passwords

I have a filter that handles BASIC authentication over HTTPS.  That means there's a header coming in named "Authorization" and the value is something like "Basic aGVsbG86c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw==".

I'm not concerned with how to handle the authentication, the 401 plus WWW-Authenticate response header, JDBC lookup or anything like that.  My filter works beautifully.

My concern is that we should never store a user password in a java.lang.String because they're immutable.  I can't zero out that String as soon as I'm done authenticating.  That object will sit in memory until the garbage collector runs.  That leaves open a much wider window for a bad guy to get a core dump or somehow otherwise observe the heap.

The problem is that the only way I see to read that Authorization header is via the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String)` method, but it returns a String.   I need a getHeader method that returns an array of bytes or chars.  Ideally, the request should never be a String at any point in time, from Socket to HttpServletRequest and everywhere in between.

If I switched to some flavor of form-based security, the problem still exists.  `javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameter(String)` returns a String too.

Is this simply a limitation of Java EE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually only string literals are keeped in String Pool area of Permgen. Created Strings are disposables.

So... Probably memory dump is one of minor problems with Basic Authentication. Others are:

- The password is sent over the wire in plaintext.
- The password is sent repeatedly, for each request. (Larger attack window)
- The password is cached by the webbrowser, at a minimum for the length of the window / process. (Can be silently reused by any other request to the server, e.g. CSRF).
- The password may be stored permanently in the browser, if the user requests. (Same as previous point, in addition might be stolen by another user on a shared machine).
- Even using SSL, internal servers (behind of SSL protocol) will have access to plain text cacheable password.

At the same time, Java container has already parsed HTTP request and populate object. So, that's why you get String from request header. You probably should rewrite the Web Container to parse safety HTTP request.

## Update

I was wrong. At least to Apache Tomcat.

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/BasicAuthenticator.java.shtml

How you can see, BasicAuthenticator from Tomcat project use MessageBytes (i.e. avoiding String) to perform the authentication.

```
/**
 * Authenticate the user making this request, based on the specified
 * login configuration.  Return <code>true if any specified
 * constraint has been satisfied, or <code>false if we have
 * created a response challenge already.
 *
 * @param request Request we are processing
 * @param response Response we are creating
 * @param config    Login configuration describing how authentication
 *              should be performed
 *
 * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
 */
public boolean authenticate(Request request,
                            Response response,
                            LoginConfig config)
    throws IOException {

    // Have we already authenticated someone?
    Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
    String ssoId = (String) request.getNote(Constants.REQ_SSOID_NOTE);
    if (principal != null) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("Already authenticated '" + principal.getName() + "'");
        // Associate the session with any existing SSO session
        if (ssoId != null)
            associate(ssoId, request.getSessionInternal(true));
        return (true);
    }

    // Is there an SSO session against which we can try to reauthenticate?
    if (ssoId != null) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("SSO Id " + ssoId + " set; attempting " +
                      "reauthentication");
        /* Try to reauthenticate using data cached by SSO.  If this fails,
           either the original SSO logon was of DIGEST or SSL (which
           we can't reauthenticate ourselves because there is no
           cached username and password), or the realm denied
           the user's reauthentication for some reason.
           In either case we have to prompt the user for a logon */
        if (reauthenticateFromSSO(ssoId, request))
            return true;
    }

    // Validate any credentials already included with this request
    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    MessageBytes authorization = 
        request.getCoyoteRequest().getMimeHeaders()
        .getValue("authorization");

    if (authorization != null) {
        authorization.toBytes();
        ByteChunk authorizationBC = authorization.getByteChunk();
        if (authorizationBC.startsWithIgnoreCase("basic ", 0)) {
            authorizationBC.setOffset(authorizationBC.getOffset() + 6);
            // FIXME: Add trimming
            // authorizationBC.trim();

            CharChunk authorizationCC = authorization.getCharChunk();
            Base64.decode(authorizationBC, authorizationCC);

            // Get username and password
            int colon = authorizationCC.indexOf(':');
            if (colon < 0) {
                username = authorizationCC.toString();
            } else {
                char[] buf = authorizationCC.getBuffer();
                username = new String(buf, 0, colon);
                password = new String(buf, colon + 1, 
                        authorizationCC.getEnd() - colon - 1);
            }

            authorizationBC.setOffset(authorizationBC.getOffset() - 6);
        }

        principal = context.getRealm().authenticate(username, password);
        if (principal != null) {
            register(request, response, principal, Constants.BASIC_METHOD,
                     username, password);
            return (true);
        }
    }


    // Send an "unauthorized" response and an appropriate challenge
    MessageBytes authenticate = 
        response.getCoyoteResponse().getMimeHeaders()
        .addValue(AUTHENTICATE_BYTES, 0, AUTHENTICATE_BYTES.length);
    CharChunk authenticateCC = authenticate.getCharChunk();
    authenticateCC.append("Basic realm=\"");
    if (config.getRealmName() == null) {
        authenticateCC.append(request.getServerName());
        authenticateCC.append(':');
        authenticateCC.append(Integer.toString(request.getServerPort()));
    } else {
        authenticateCC.append(config.getRealmName());
    }
    authenticateCC.append('\"');        
    authenticate.toChars();
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    //response.flushBuffer();
    return (false);

}
```

As long you have access to org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, no worries.

## So, How can you avoid parsing of HTTP request

There's an amazing answer here in stackoverflow detailing

[Use servlet filter to remove a form parameter from posted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601279/use-servlet-filter-to-remove-a-form-parameter-from-posted-data)

and an important explanation:

> Approach
>
> The code follows the correct approach:
>
> in wrapRequest(), it instantiates HttpServletRequestWrapper and overrides the 4 methods that trigger request parsing:
>
> public String getParameter(String name)
>   public Map getParameterMap()
>   public Enumeration getParameterNames()
>   public String[] getParameterValues(String name)
>   the doFilter() method invokes the filter chain using the wrapped request, meaning subsequent filters, plus the target servlet (URL-mapped) will be supplied the wrapped request.

Comment: I acknowledge the limitations of Basic Auth.  However, the password is not sent over the wire in plaintext when using HTTPS.  HTTPS prevents eavesdropping, so hopefully the connection is confidential between the user's browser and my server.  My server is what's running the Servlet Filter.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Password is not sent over the wire in plaintext. But, In Tomcat application Server, by default, the user's password is stored in clear text for each of the standard Realm implementations. Sometimes, you can also use an Apache Server in front of Tomcat Server with ajp connector. Finally, if you are using Tomcat directly, HTTPS will prevent eavesdropping.

Comment: Okay, I can see why you pointed that out.  We already have a user table in our application that has a hashed password field.  My Servlet Filter authenticates against it.

Comment: I don't think I need to worry with wrapping the Request.  I could use the `request.getCoyoteRequest.getMimeHeaders().getValue(String)` method to get a char[] for the password and then maybe even zero it out after I've performed my authentication.  I'm not crazy about tying it to Tomcat, since we have some customers who run different web containers.  I could go with the default `getHeader(String)` method if not Tomcat and this crazy way when I'm in Tomcat.  Wow.

Comment: Thanks @rdllopes.  Ultimately, we're not going to put vendor-specific stuff in our servlets, even if it is Tomcat.  I do consider my question answered since you've confirmed that J2EE doesn't provide a mechanism for this and because you offered a workaround.  We may come back to it one day, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct but it should never store in db an actual password to check against but instead a hash on the password itself then run a hash to determine if the two hashes are identical which a password is never used but by the original user.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the JDBC bit (second paragraph of original question).  I'm using a bcrypt hash.

Answer (score 0):

if you are that concerned then use `ServletRequest.getInputStream()` instead of `HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String)` in your `Filter`. You should be able get your HTTP request as a stream, skip till you get to `Authorization` header and get your password in a `char []`.

But all this effort might be futile as the underlying object is still a `HTTPServletRequest` and might contain all the headers as key val pairs in a map, details being subject to how servlet is implemented.

Comment: Sorry, getInputStream only returns the body of the request.  The headers are before the body.  You're right though, the container may render this futile (thus my comment about the request from Socket to HttpServletRequest in the original question).

Comment: my bad just put my thought process into this answer without testing it